# static variable called in function giving error undefined codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, static-variables

I have defined static variable in controller but when I use that variable in functions it is giving undefined variable error.

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Quiz extends Admin_Controller {

    private static $secure_key = "aXXXXXXXXc";

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        try
        {
            $token = JWT::encode($postdata, $secure_key);
            echo "<pre>";print_r($token);exit; 
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            $this->data['error'] = $e->getMessage();
            redirect('/','refresh');
       }
    }
}
```

`$token` gets printed properly with jwt but I am getting an error

> **`Undefined variable: secure_key`**

I tried different methods to define `$secure_key` as

```
public static $secure_key = "aXXXXXXXc;
static $secure_key = "aXXXXXXXc;
```

I tried to define `$secure_key` in constructor also as 
`$secure_key = "aXXXXXXXc;`

but no use. Why so? Please help. I am using codeigniter 3

Comment: `$token = JWT::encode($postdata, $secure_key);` ... `$postdata` appears to be undefined and `$secure_key` is a static class variable (so `self::$secure_key`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Recommended Method (*Based on Security*)

Define variables in `config.php` and access it. This will work like **Global Variable**

```
$config['secure_key'] = 'myKey';
$this->config->item('secure_key'); # get
$this->config->set_item('secure_key', 'NewKey'); # set
```

---

Access it like this

```
$this->$secure_key
```

As per [Comment by cd001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807136/static-variable-called-in-function-giving-error-undefined-codeigniter-php#comment80561641_46807229)

```
self::$secure_key
```

If function

```
$this->function_name();
```

Comment: `$secure_key` is static ... so `self::$secure_key` rather than `$this->secure_key`

Comment: yeah any value which is used in the project globally, must be defined in `config.php` and should be loaded from `config` inside the code

Comment: Thanks a lo it works. This means whenever I define static variable in codeigniter I need to write 
`self::$secure_key` 
or
`class_name::$variale_name` 
to use it right.

Comment: But @Abdulla if we define in config still we can change its value as given in answer as `item` and `set_item`. What if I dont want to change value of that variable, then static would be much prefarable?

Answer (score 3):

Since `$secure_key` is declared as `static` inside your class. So it can be accessed using `self` or `className` as

```
self::$secure_key
```

or

```
Quiz::$secure_key
```